# How to sync Core Data with iCloud in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

Is it possible to synch `Core Data` with **iCloud**? I read somewhere that Apple doesn't support this anymore. What should we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment – macOS10.12 and iOS10 – iCloud Core Data is deprecated but still operational.

In the next major releases macOS10.13 and iOS11 the functionality will be (probably) removed and you have to use CloudKit or a third party solution.

Comment: CloudKit does not sync to a persistent local database.

Comment: Have a look at Ensembles.